# Invalid redirect URI for spotify

Tags: angularjs, spotify

I'm trying to get the Spotify API working with AngularJS. I'm getting an invalid redirect URI error at the authorization stage (https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/).

I have added the redirect_uri in the white list and it works when I have a URI such as

```
http://localhost:3000
```

but it doesn't work when I have a URI with a hash

```
http://localhost:3000/#/main
```

The reason I want to use the latter URI is because with the former I get a URI which I can't get the parameters from via angular

```
http://localhost:3000/<parameters returned from spotify>/#/main)
```

whereas I'd expect the URI to be like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/#/main/<parameters returned from spotify>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Not very knowledgeable in Angular, but couldn't you create a specific endpoint on your backend to just receive the authorization code, e.g. http://<hostname>:3000/handle-auth/, that redirects to /#/main?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you can do it. I recommend you to have a look at the [possan/webapi-player-example](https://github.com/possan/webapi-player-example), which is built using AngularJS and uses a `PostMessage` to communicate between the redirect URI (`callback.html`) and the Angular app (`app.js`).

If PostMessages is not an option, you can try this:

1. Start a loop to check a certain key on `localStorage`
2. Open the login page in a popup.
3. From the callback page, write in `localStorage` the data you get back from Spotify (i.e. `access_token`, `refresh_token`, `expires_in`).
4. Close the popup after a couple of seconds
5. The loop should have realised about the new value being written in localStorage.

The previous flow, although a bit more complex, works well in environments such as iOS devices where it is sometimes impossible to communicate between the callback page and the "main" page properly.

Comment: I've given it a go and i've managed to get the token, thanks.