# Android Spotify SDK Login error Unexpected token

Tags: android, json, authentication, uri, spotify

I'm trying to implement Spotify SDK on an android app, when I click the button the Spotify activity starts just fine but when I try to login nothing happens and it logs me an `Unexpected token error`, I used the exact same code as in the Spotify tutorials, hope you can help

```
    06-29 13:40:36.677 4708-4708/com.app.project.silverbars I/chromium: [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(60)] Async pixel transfers not supported
06-29 13:40:36.789 4708-4708/com.app.project.silverbars I/chromium: [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(60)] Async pixel transfers not supported
06-29 13:40:37.505 4708-4708/com.app.project.silverbars D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1600K, 15% free 9975K/11700K, paused 6ms, total 6ms
06-29 13:41:02.605 4708-4708/com.app.project.silverbars I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(6)] "SyntaxError: Unexpected token I
                                                                        at Object.parse (native)
                                                                        at Y (https://d2d1dxiu3v1f2i.cloudfront.net/19b92cb/js/index.js:5:6501)
                                                                        at xt (https://d2d1dxiu3v1f2i.cloudfront.net/19b92cb/js/index.js:6:14454)
                                                                        at https://d2d1dxiu3v1f2i.cloudfront.net/19b92cb/js/index.js:6:14923
                                                                        at i (https://d2d1dxiu3v1f2i.cloudfront.net/19b92cb/js/index.js:5:1297)
                                                                        at Tt (https://d2d1dxiu3v1f2i.cloudfront.net/19b92cb/js/index.js:6:14933)
                                                                        at o (https://d2d1dxiu3v1f2i.cloudfront.net/19b92cb/js/index.js:6:15632)
                                                                        at s (https://d2d1dxiu3v1f2i.cloudfront.net/19b92cb/js/index.js:7:2578)
                                                                        at https://d2d1dxiu3v1f2i.cloudfront.net/19b92cb/js/index.js:7:2750
                                                                        at f.$eval (https://d2d1dxiu3v1f2i.cloudfront.net/19b92cb/js/index.js:7:10267)", source: https://d2d1dxiu3v1f2i.cloudfront.net/19b92cb/js/index.js (6)
```

SpotifyActivity:

```
public class SpotifyMusic extends AppCompatActivity implements
        PlayerNotificationCallback, ConnectionStateCallback {

    // TODO: Replace with your client ID
    private static final String CLIENT_ID = "b51d25ed8e514fa5927c028d5827a358";
    // TODO: Replace with your redirect URI
    private static final String REDIRECT_URI = "yourcustomprotocol://callback";

    // Request code that will be passed together with authentication result to the onAuthenticationResult callback
    // Can be any integer
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1337;

    private Player mPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_spotify_music);

        AuthenticationRequest.Builder builder =
                new AuthenticationRequest.Builder(CLIENT_ID, AuthenticationResponse.Type.TOKEN, REDIRECT_URI);
        builder.setScopes(new String[]{"user-read-private", "streaming"});
        AuthenticationRequest request = builder.build();

        AuthenticationClient.openLoginActivity(this, REQUEST_CODE, request);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        // Check if result comes from the correct activity
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            AuthenticationResponse response = AuthenticationClient.getResponse(resultCode, intent);
            if (response.getType() == AuthenticationResponse.Type.TOKEN) {
                Config playerConfig = new Config(this, response.getAccessToken(), CLIENT_ID);
                mPlayer = Spotify.getPlayer(playerConfig, this, new Player.InitializationObserver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInitialized(Player player) {
                        mPlayer.addConnectionStateCallback(SpotifyMusic.this);
                        mPlayer.addPlayerNotificationCallback(SpotifyMusic.this);
                        mPlayer.play("spotify:track:2TpxZ7JUBn3uw46aR7qd6V");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                        Log.e("MainActivity", "Could not initialize player: " + throwable.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoggedIn() {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "User logged in");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoggedOut() {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "User logged out");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoginFailed(Throwable error) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Login failed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTemporaryError() {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Temporary error occurred");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionMessage(String message) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Received connection message: " + message);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPlaybackEvent(EventType eventType, PlayerState playerState) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Playback event received: " + eventType.name());
        switch (eventType) {
            // Handle event type as necessary
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPlaybackError(ErrorType errorType, String errorDetails) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Playback error received: " + errorType.name());
        switch (errorType) {
            // Handle error type as necessary
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // VERY IMPORTANT! This must always be called or else you will leak resources
        Spotify.destroyPlayer(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your redirect_uri should match with the redirect_uri mentioned under my apps on the Spotify Developer Console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get is actually a JSON error at `JSON.parse()`

> Throws a SyntaxError exception if the string to parse is not valid JSON.

After looking at your code, I can see that you **have not** followed precisely the tutorial.There is stated

> The completed code of MainActivity.java should now look like this, *but with your own client ID and redirect URI*:

Because your `redirect URI` is not set

```
private static final String REDIRECT_URI = "yourcustomprotocol://callback";
```

your URI can't get parsed. Which is not by coincidence related to your error, since the redirect URI is used in the login process and basically is the *location the client will get send to after a successful account authorization*.

Now about how you could set it up, I couldn't help you much since I haven't worked with the Spotify SDK, but you could use something like

```
private static final String REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost:PORT_NUMBER://authenticationResponse"
```

`PORT_NUMBER` can be anything greater than 1024

For more info, this question might be helpful: [Spotify redirect URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25229071/invalid-redirect-uri-for-spotify).

Hopefully you will get this one sorted out.

Comment: i really dont understand the "REDIRECT_URI", why do i need a localhost for parse the json? do i have to create another file for parse the redirect uri?