# HashRouter causes Spotify Implicit Grant Flow to fail because callback URL is invalid

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, spotify, react-router-dom, callbackurl

I have a HashRouter, which makes the URL add #, resulting in # to be added after the URL callback response_type query parameter.

If you change # to %23, it will lead to Invalid redirect URI.

How can I combine the use of HashRouter, and the Spotify Implicit Grant Flow?

I put my application on the github page: [githubpage](https://hsienw.github.io/music-demo/#/)

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution to fix this is, assuming your redirect URI is `http://localhost:8000/#/callback`, to add a Route to your HashRouter with a regex:

`<Route path="/:access_token(access_token=.*)" component={ComponentWhichParsesTheURLAndExtractTheToken} />`

This will direct **any** url of the type `http://localhost:8000/#/access_token=`to the desired component. The desired component should be the one where you parse the url to capture the token.

If you use the Spotify function `getHashParams()` from their [implicit grant example](https://github.com/spotify/web-api-auth-examples/blob/master/implicit_grant/public/index.html) to capture the hash params also change this line :

```
q = window.location.hash.substring(1);
```

to

```
q = window.location.hash.substring(2);
```

in order to remove the first character `/` from the `window.location.hash` path.

There is probably a better solution (see [this answer for angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25229071/invalid-redirect-uri-for-spotify?rq=1)) for this problem, although I figured this is a quick hack that works for *modest* applications.